# Heroku DB deployment

Tags: heroku

I'm attempting my first Heroku deployment and am having trouble

```
heroku pg:backups:restore "https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/myusername/POSTGRESQL.dump" 
                          DATABASE_URL --app MyAppName
```

I receive the error

```
 !    An error occurred and the backup did not finish.
 !
 !    pg_restore: [archiver] did not find magic string in file header
 !    pg_restore finished with errors
 !    waiting for download to complete
 !    download finished with errors
 !    please check the source URL and ensure it is publicly accessible
 !
 !    Run heroku pg:backups:info r006 for more details.
```

And sometimes the error is:

```
Starting restore of https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/talXXXXXXXX to postgresql-XXXXXXXXX... done

Use Ctrl-C at any time to stop monitoring progress; the ba
Use heroku pg:backups to check progress.
Stop a running restore with heroku pg:backups:cancel.

Restoring... !
 !    An error occurred and the backup did not finish.
 !
 !    waiting for restore to complete
 !    pg_restore finished with errors
 !    waiting for download to complete
 !    download finished with errors
 !    please check the source URL and ensure it is publicl
 !
 !    Run heroku pg:backups:info r015 for more details.
```

I have confirmed from various browsers that the url is accessible to the public and I can download the file. I'm using double quotes around the URL as recommended for Windows, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If I modify the URL to something invalid, I get the same error. So it is just as likely that it is not properly parsing the URL as it is that public accessibility is an issue

Answer (score 8):

I was facing the same problem. Turn out it was a problem with my dump file. I wasn't compressing it properly.

`--format=c` selects custom as the format output (which is the same as `-Fc`). It compress the file by default, but it wasn't enough so I also used the `--compress` flag.

This flag tells the level of the compression; it goes from 0 (lighter) to 9 (heavier).

I used 9, just in case, and my command end up like that

```
pg_dump --format=c --compress=9 --no-acl --no-owner -h THE_HOST -U YOUR_USER THE_DATABASE > YOUR_FILE.dump
```

And it worked.

Comment: Just wanted to confirm this worked for me by first creating the dump file with: `pg_dump --format=c --compress=9 -U postgres myapp_production > pg_15_aug_18.sql` then doing the restore with `heroku pg:backups:restore "mysite.org/uploads/tmp/pg_15_aug_18.sql" DATABASE_URL`

Comment: Also just confirming that this worked for me, but **also** needed to use an unsigned (totally public) URL rather than a signed URL.  Heroku instructs to use a signed S3 URL, but I couldn't get that to work properly.  Thanks for this answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I couldn't work out how to import to Heroku as they advertise it can be done at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export#import

So I used a DB connection client like DBeaver, converted my DB dump into an SQL script and ran the script manually to import the data.

:(

Comment: Hi. Can you be more specific about how you converted your dump file and ran the script? I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by creating the backup through PgAdmin4, rather than through the console dump command on Heroku's official tutorial.

Comment: what options did you use in the pgadmin4 backup? I have tried both the CLI and that one and couldn't get it to work..

Comment: I'm sorry - I don't recall, other than it was mostly default settings.

Answer (score 0):

I also could only get this working through PgAdmin, here's the command line that the backup job in PgAdmin used. Windows 10 but the pg_dump options should work on any OS.

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin\pg_dump.exe --file "mydump.dump" --host "localhost" --port "5432" --username "postgres" --no-password --verbose --format=c --blobs --compress "8" --no-owner --section=pre-data --section=data --section=post-data --no-privileges --no-tablespaces --no-unlogged-table-data --no-comments "mydatabase"
```

I then uploaded that to a public Azure blob file and restored it like this:

```
heroku pg:backups:restore "https://redacted.blob.core.windows.net/piis2/mydump.dump" DATABASE_URL
```